# MySQL joined query count returning a row for each result

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, group-by, left-join

So, I'm doing a custom wordpress query to pull events (Events are stored in custom fields (meta data) hence the need for the JOINs) and I want to get a count of the rows returned. My problem is that I'm getting a bunch of rows returned each containing a count against each post ID returned.

My query looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   wp_posts AS wposts 
   LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS metafeatured 
          ON wposts.id = metafeatured.post_id 
   LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS metastart 
          ON wposts.id = metastart.post_id 
   LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaend 
          ON wposts.id = metaend.post_id 
   LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
          ON ( wposts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
   LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
          ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 
               wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) 
WHERE  wposts.post_type = 'll_events' 
   AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
   AND ( ( ( metastart.meta_key = 'll_events_startdate' 
             AND Cast(metastart.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) < 1342997940 ) 
           AND ( metaend.meta_key = 'll_events_enddate' 
                 AND Cast(metaend.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) > 1342525664 ) ) 
          OR ( ( metastart.meta_key = 'll_events_startdate' 
                 AND Cast(metastart.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) <= 1342997940 ) 
               AND ( metaend.meta_key = 'll_events_enddate' 
                     AND Cast(metaend.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) >= 1342525664 
                   ) ) 
          OR ( ( metastart.meta_key = 'll_events_startdate' 
                 AND Cast(metastart.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 
                     1342525664 AND 1342997940 
                   ) 
               AND ( metastart.meta_key = 'll_events_enddate' 
                     AND Cast(metaend.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 
                         1342525664 AND 1342997940 
                   ) ) 
          OR ( ( metastart.meta_key = 'll_events_startdate' 
                 AND Cast(metastart.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN 
                     1342525664 AND 1342997940 
                   ) 
               AND ( metaend.meta_key = 'll_events_enddate' 
                     AND Cast(metaend.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) <= 1 ) ) ) 
GROUP BY wposts.ID, metastart.post_id, metaend.post_id, wp_term_relationships.object_id
ORDER BY metastart.meta_value ASC
```

I've tried loads of combinations of group, count and such and can't get the expected result (a single row in the result-set containing a 'count'). Instead, my resultset looks something like:

```
count(*)
24
30
30
30
12
16
1
```

... and so on, where I need:

```
count(*)
139
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the GROUP BY Clause